# The UITableViewDelegate didDeselectRowAt method doesn't get called when the row is tapped again

Tags: swift

I have a dummy dynamic table view. Each cell contains just a label. When the cell is tapped for the first time, a checkmark appears. Tapping on it for the second time, should make the cell's `accessoryType` be `none`. I implement both `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` methods of `UITableViewDelegate`. Here they are:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print ("TT Did select at indexPath \(indexPath)")

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print ("TT didDeselect at \(indexPath)")

}
```

The problem is, when I tap on a cell that is already tapped (with a checkmark) the `didDeselectRowAt` method doesn't get called, but instead, the `didSelectRowAt` method gets called again. The `didDeselectRowAt` method gets called only when I tap on another row.

I know I'm missing something simple, but can't figure it out. Do you have any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: didDeselectRowAt method not called when you select same cell those you have before select

Comment: @iParesh, yes I've completely forgotten about that. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this methods like below than Selected row selection misplaced while you scroll your `tableView`. `(multiple selection)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print ("TT Did select at indexPath \(indexPath)")
        let cell: TableViewCell = self.tblVW.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print ("TT didDeselect at \(indexPath)")
        let cell: TableViewCell = self.tblVW.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

I suggest you to add selected row `indexPath` in `array` and in `cellForItem` method check that `array` contains that `indexPath`? If it contains than set `.checkmark` otherwise set `.none` like below

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 30
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:TableViewCell = self.tblVW.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

            cell.textLabel?.text = String.init(format: "Row %d", indexPath.row)

            if arrIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
                cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
            else {
                cell?.accessoryType = .none
            }

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print ("TT Did select at indexPath \(indexPath)")
            if (arrIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)) {
                arrIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)
            }
            else {
                arrIndexPaths.add(indexPath)
            }
            self.tblVW.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: I forgot that `didSelectRowAt` is called when `allowsMultipleSelection` is set to `true`. Without that, your solution is the best, although I don't need to keep an array of `IndexPaths`. Only a single one is enough, since the user can check only one row. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selection type as "Multiple Selection"[image]

Comment: Yes, in that case it works, I know. But isn't it possible to call the method when the property is set to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious. According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview , didSelect is called whenever you 'select' it. Keep a variable called 'recentRow' which keep the last tapped row index. If it is 'didSelect' again, then you can remove the checkmark